# Mooc.fi Part 3 Help,

Tags: java

Confused on this exercise, its asking me to create a loop which remembers multiple integers that the user inputted, and prints them out the exact same way. I'm confused on how to print the input without making it a list and not using any methods. I tried making input equal to i, but that doesn't output anything.

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
        int i2 = 0;
        ArrayList <Integer> name_input = new ArrayList<>();
        while(true) {
            System.out.print("print number:");
            int input = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
            name_input.add(input);
            
            if (input == -1) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
            }
        while(i2 < i){
            System.out.println(i);
            i2++;
        }
    }
```

Original question: The exercise template contains a base that reads numbers from the user and adds them to a list. Reading is stopped once the user enters the number -1.

Expand the functionality of the program so that after reading the numbers, it prints all the numbers received from the user. The number used to indicate stopping should not be printed.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question,  what do you mean by "how to print the input without making it a list and not using any methods"?

Comment: When I do System.out.println(name_input); it prints out the user input, but in the form of a list. The expected output is supposed to be in the form of an integer